# How to increase the value of a column by 1 based on the value of other column else doesn't increment the value?

Tags: sql, scope

I have a table with column (difference).

```
difference  tableNumber

     10    
     22    
     03    
     45    
     32    
     120   
     65    
     34    
     85    
     90    
     130   
     140   
     65    
     21    
     01    
     45    
     150   
     55    
     5000  
     87    
     43
```

The first rows tableNumber will start with '1'.

```
difference  tableNumber

     10          1
     22    
     03    
     45    
     32    
     120   
     65    
     34    
     85    
     90    
     130   
     140   
     65    
     21    
     01    
     45    
     150   
     55    
     5000  
     87    
     43
```

Now, (from second row onwards) if the 'difference' < 100 then insert the 'tableNumber' of previous rows' value

else if the 'difference' > 100 then increment the value of 'tableNumber' of previous row by 1 and insert it in the current row.

Edit: Sample table: (tableNumber is the expected output)

So, this will be the expected output:

```
 difference tableNumber 

     10          1         
     22          1      
     03          1      
     45          1      
     32          1      
     120         2      
     65          2      
     34          2      
     85          2      
     90          2      
     130         3      
     140         4      
     65          4      
     21          4      
     01          4      
     45          4      
     150         5      
     55          5      
     5000        6      
     87          6      
     43          6
```

Comment: Please include sample data which explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle? These are all very different RDBMS and no answer will work on all 3. I've removed all 3 of these tags; please update your post and tag *only* the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" row?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have included the sample data

Comment: @melpomene I have added the sample data. Might you get clarity on what the first row means

Comment: No, my question stands. How are these rows ordered?

Comment: @melpomene difference column values can be of any order. But the tableNumber columns logic will be same - Increment the value by 1 if the 'difference' column value is greater than 100

Comment: You're not answering my question. You're just repeating what you've already said before.

Comment: @melpomene I didn't get what you mean by that. But as far as my understanding goes, tableNumber column will be in ascending order

Comment: A table is essentially a set of rows. There is no "first row" or "previous row". If you want the rows to be in a specific order, you have to sort them (by some criterion).

Comment: @melpomene I have edited the question. Hope this might clear your doubt

Comment: I have no doubts. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  What you want to do seems to depend on the ordering of the rows.  I will assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Let's call it `ord`.

I think the following basically does what you want:

```
select difference,
       1 + sum(case when difference < 100 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by ord) as tablenumber
from t;
```

This does not take into account the first "1" in the table.  However, that seems superfluous to the problem you really want to solve (identifying adjacent groups where the values are less than 100).

If that is important, you can replace the `1 +` with something like `(select difference from t order by ord fetch first row only) +` -- or whatever expression is appropriate for your database.